# Google studio filter to show values less than 95% not working at all

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am trying to create a chart that shows agents with performance less than 95% only. i am trying the filter feature while creating the chart. for some reason it will never work showing agents less than 95%. i even tried creating a pivot table to filter agents with less than 95% but its the same also.

i wonder what im doing wrong here!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Utilization value ranges so we will likely need more information to answer this. Saying that, have you tried to exclude values less than 95 rather than 0.95?
Just an initial thought.